# Connection timeout

Tags: .net, sql

Im getting this error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

```
"Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Reset=False;"
```

Connection pooling is default to true and I am closing all connections.

Any ideas?

Comment: What technology are you using? ASP.NET, .NET winforms, php, etc... also what DBMS?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting ConnectionTimeout and/or CommandTimeout (if working on .NET). A timeout of 0 means "no timeout"

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the SQL server does not allow incoming TCP/IP connections (which is the default setting).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the connnection string as follows

You can try any one of them, Connect Timeout=0 or Connection Timeout=0

```
"Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=0;"
```

Connect Timeout=0 or Connection Timeout=0 meaning infinite time for the operation to run

refer the following [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is this problem occuring on only one page? or is it a global issue?

Are you aware of what query is causing the timeout?

- If not, you should add try/catches around your database calls and log your errors to determine where it is.
- If so, can you run that query from your database tool? (IE SQL Server Management Studio)

  - Does your query succeed? or does it timeout?
  - Does it take a long time? Can you improve the performance of that query?

Comment: are we even sure it's a page? could be winforms or something else entirely.

Comment: not sure, I just left a comment to clarify, I mean to determine if it's only one query as opposed to the actual connection.